# Uploading to youtube

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am doing an application where in I upload some videos to S3 (public mode). Then I want to schedule a job which will be given the S3 link and it needs to upload the video to youtube using one particular account.

How can I do that?

I am using PHP as the language (Gearman for background task processing). I need help in uploading to youtube. Is there some resource where I can find out how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go directly [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Uploading_Videos), and check what suits best your needs. I guess you should consider Direct Uploading. Scheduling a job may be achieved with cron jobs (crontab -e on linux). More details about crontab [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/manual/html_node/Crontab-file.html).

Comment: Is there a PHP library which I can use?

Comment: You can use Zend library: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Direct_Upload